# Javascript regex help

Tags: javascript, regex, string, escaping

I have the following string in JavaScript

```
  var mystring = " abcdef(p,q); check(x,y); cef(m,n);"
```

I would want to do a string replace such that my final string   is :

```
  mystring = " abcdef(p,q); someothercheck\(x,y\); cef(m,n);"
```

x and y should remain same after the substitution. and the backslashes are necessary since I need to pass them to some other command.

There can be  other Parantheses in the string too.

Comment: Why a regex? Just string-replace " check" with " someothercheck" and "(" with "\\(" and ")" with "\\)".

Comment: like mystring.replace('check','somothercheck').replace('(','\\\(').replace(')','\\\)'); http://jsfiddle.net/ytnRx/

Comment: 3 regexes are better than one

Comment: I have edited the question . Please see that paranthses are present elsewhere and @stebs method won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have other parenthesis, it should be easy.

```
mystring = mystring.replace("check(", "someothercheck\\(");
mystring = mystring.replace(")", "\\)");
```

**EDIT** This works also in the case of multiple parenthesis (It does not affect the empty ones).
    var str=" abcdef; check(x,y); cef();"
        patt = /((\w)/g;

```
// transform (x in \(x
str = str.replace(patt, '\\($1');

patt = /(\w)\)/g

// transform y) in y\);
str = str.replace(patt,  '$1\\)');

// transform check in someothercheck
str = str.replace('check', 'someothercheck');
```

**EDIT** Now it converts only the check strings.

```
function convertCheck(str, check, someOtherCheck) {
   // console.log(str + " contains " + check + "? ");
   // console.log(str.indexOf(check));

   if (str.indexOf(check) === -1) return str;
   var patt1 = /\((\w)/g,
   patt2 = /(\w)\)/g; 

   str = str.replace(patt1, '\\($1');
   str = str.replace(patt2,  '$1\\)');
   str = str.replace(check, someOtherCheck);

   return str;
}

var str = "abcdef(); check(x,y); cef();",
    tokens = str.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   tokens[i] = convertCheck(tokens[i], "check", "someothercheck");
}
str = tokens.join(";");

alert(str);  // "abcdef(); someothercheck/(x,y/); cef();"
```

Comment: Don't take him literally. Consider `someothercheck` as an example

Comment: I have edited the question.There are other parantheses in the string too.

Comment: @Pablo, Don't take him (@user278064) literally. Consider the answer as an example.

Comment: @user270349 I am sorry my question wasn't clear ! I need to check it with the string : "func1(a,b,c); func2(a,v,b);  check (x,y); cef(c,d)"

Comment: It wasn't me, it was @user278064

Answer (score 2):

```
var myString = "abcdef; check(x,y); cef;";

myString.replace(/(\w+)\(/, 'someother$1(')
        .replace(/\(/g, '\\(')
        .replace(/\)/g, '\\)')
```

Comment: I have edited the question. We need to take into account that there are other parantheses in the string too.